# Как сделать адаптивные фоновые изображения, как на  fl.ru

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, css

Хочу сверстать [этот](https://dribbble.com/shots/1614563-Free-PSD-for-Single-Page-Portfolio) макет. При масштабировании фоновое изображение масштабируется не пропорционально. Хочу, как на fl.ru: 
 [ссылка](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0225/15/f024851d73b11ad384494c898a41d715.jpg),
 [ссылка](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0225/b1/9d5fd82adfffcd5cb116bb1bbb2f3db1.jpg).

Хотел изучить исходный код fl.ru, но там очень много классов, разобраться очень трудно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/yhr5ch2n/

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 445px;
}
```

2) http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1qmgehaa/

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

div{
    position: relative;
}
div img{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;    
}
```

3) http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mxw0Lmbj/

HTML

```
<div>    
    <figure></figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
}
div figure{
    padding-top: 36.56%;  /* 702px/1920px = 0.3656 */
    display: block;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;  
}
```